# SQL0443 error when executing a Select with a Trigger on DB2 for iSeries

Tags: db2, spring-batch, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I've some problem querying a db2/as400 table, let's call it TAB1. Since it was added a trigger on this table when I perform a normal SELECT (using the TAB1-key) I get the following error. Never had a problem before the trigger was created.

It's a query performed in a batch-application (Java 1.6) using Modern Batch and Spring Batch 2.1.8. No chance to update the libraries, since the program is quite old and the customers won't agree.

Anyway,I would say it's a trigger problem ( as the sql codes say) but different applications perform different SELECTs on TAB1 and they never get any similar problem.The batch perform more or less 40000 select like this, and just 300 fail with this error.

Any idea, tip, suggestion?

```
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0443] *N *N  
### The error may exist in class path resource [eu/mycompany/el20/dq/as400/dataaccess/mappers/tab1/Tab1Mapper.xml]  
### The error may involve eu.mycompany.el20.dq.as400.dataaccess.persistence.tab.Tab1Mapper.selectByExample-Inline  
### The error occurred while setting parameters  
### SQL: select * from  TAB1 WHERE (  D10_SOC = ? and D10_COD_NDG = ?  and D10_DATE = ? )  
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0443] *N *N  
; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [38501]; error code [-443]; [SQL0443] *N *N; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0443] *N *Nstack trace: org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)  
org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)  
org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)  
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:71)  
org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:365)  
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.selectList(Unknown Source)  
org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:195)  
org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:124)  
org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:90)  
org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:40)  
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy136.selectByExample(Unknown Source)  
eu.mycompany.el20.dq.as400.crud.services.tab.BLSTab1.select(BLSTab1.java:46)  
it.mycompany.xframe.dq.batch.steps.programstep.ProgramExecutor.processRecord(ProgramExecutor.java:544)  
com.ibm.websphere.batch.devframework.steps.technologyadapters.GenericXDBatchStep.processRecord(GenericXDBatchStep.java:263)  
com.ibm.websphere.batch.devframework.steps.technologyadapters.GenericXDBatchStep.processJobStep(GenericXDBatchStep.java:227)  
com.ibm.ws.gridcontainer.batch.impl.StepManagerImpl._regularJobBatchLoop(StepManagerImpl.java:1065)  
com.ibm.ws.gridcontainer.batch.impl.StepManagerImpl.executeStep(StepManagerImpl.java:390)  
com.ibm.ws.gridcontainer.security.actions.ExecuteStepBatchUserPrivilegedAction.executeAction(ExecuteStepBatchUserPrivilegedAction.java:47)  
com.ibm.ws.gridcontainer.security.AbstractUserPrivilegedAction.runWithoutSecurity(AbstractUserPrivilegedAction.java:66)  
com.ibm.ws.gridcontainer.services.impl.WASRunUnderCredentialServiceImpl.runUnderUserCredential(WASRunUnderCredentialServiceImpl.java:134)  
com.ibm.ws.gridcontainer.services.impl.WASRunUnderCredentialServiceImpl.runActionUnderUserCredential(WASRunUnderCredentialServiceImpl.java:386)  
com.ibm.ws.gridcontainer.batch.impl.JobManagerImpl._sequentialStepScheduling(JobManagerImpl.java:783)  
com.ibm.ws.gridcontainer.batch.impl.JobManagerImpl.executeJob(JobManagerImpl.java:199)  
com.ibm.ws.batch.BatchJobControllerWork._runJob(BatchJobControllerWork.java:435)  
com.ibm.ws.batch.BatchJobControllerWork.run(BatchJobControllerWork.java:241)  
com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext$RunProxy.run(J2EEContext.java:271)  
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)  
com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:797)  
com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.go(WorkWithExecutionContextImpl.java:222)  
com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.ABWorkItemImpl.run(ABWorkItemImpl.java:206)  
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:790)
```

Answer (score 2):

The text for message SQL0443 is 'Trigger program or external routine detected an error'.

I would suggest looking at the host database server job for the JDBC connection.

On the IBM i command line, run the command `WRKOBJLCK OBJ(<user>) OBJTYPE(*USRPRF)` (where <user> is the user profile you're using to do the JDBC connection) and find jobs named `QZDASOINIT`. These are the database host server jobs.

In these jobs, look at the joblog (or joblog spool file) to find the SQL0443 message ... around that message you should see what the actual error is.